# Query on usage of on-premises data gateway for connecting Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, sql-server-2017, azure-analysis-services, data-gateway

I have an application hosted in Azure infrastructure IaaS model. In this case, database: SQL Server 2017 is managed using Azure VM. For enhanced security isolation , the entire setup including the database server is leveraging VNets. Now we are planning to leverage Azure Analysis Services: PaaS offering to host the data models in the Azure environment and allow the client apps: Excel to connect it to  create reports and perform ad-hoc data analysis on the data.

Since in this case both the data source and the Azure Analysis service are hosted in Azure environment, do we still need to use On-premises Data Gateway to connect the Tabular Models hosted in Azure Analysis Services with  the data sources hosted in Azure VM through On-premises Data Gateway

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance on this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below links which answers for your query

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-vnet-gateway

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-network-faq

Data source connections:

Question - I have a VNET for my data source system. How can I allow my Analysis Services servers to access the database from the VNET?

Answer - Azure Analysis Services is unable to join a VNET. The best solution here is to install and configure an On-premises Data Gateway on the VNET, and then configure your Analysis Services servers with the AlwaysUseGateway server property. To learn more, see Use gateway for data sources on an Azure Virtual Network (VNet).

Comment: Thanks @user12395612 for your response. It helped me a lot :)